# <scala> How the scope delegation works in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

I've read a [reference](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Scope-Delegation.html) to understand how the scope delegation works in SBT.

From the above reference page, I excerpted an Exercise D.

```
ThisBuild / scalacOptions += "-Ywarn-unused-import"

lazy val projD = (project in file("d"))
  .settings(
    test := {
      println((Compile / console / scalacOptions).value)
    },
    console / scalacOptions -= "-Ywarn-unused-import",
    Compile / scalacOptions := scalacOptions.value // added by sbt
  )
```

> What would you see if you ran projD/test?
>
> List()
>
> List (-Ywarn-unused-import)
>
> something else?

And their reasoning was

> The answer is List(-Ywarn-unused-import). Rule 2 finds projD / Compile / Zero, Rule 3 finds projD / Zero / console, and Rule 4 finds ThisBuild / Zero / Zero. Rule 1 selects projD / Compile / Zero because it has the subproject axis projD, and the configuration axis has higher precedence over the task axis.

So far so good, I could understand the reason why Compile/console/sclacOptions will be scoped to projD/Compile/zero/scalacOptions. It's because the configuration axis of projD/Compile/zero is more concrete than the projD/zero/console compared to the key that we want to know (Compile/console/scalacOptions).

> Next, Compile / scalacOptions refers to scalacOptions.value, we next need to find a delegate for projD / Zero / Zero. Rule 4 finds ThisBuild / Zero / Zero and thus it resolves to List(-Ywarn-unused-import).

Here, I couldn't understand why ThisBuild / Zero/ Zero wins the projD/ Compile/ Zero. Because the scope of the key that we want to find is projD/ zero/ zero, so projD/Compile/zero has more specific value compared to the Thisbuild [Following the Rule 1 in the reference].

I think the reason is Compile/ scalacOptions has the value of scalacOptions.value, which generates recursive definition. Then, we could have used the projD/ Zero/ console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're just a bit confused about the references to the difference scopes in the second part of the explanation. Let's write down all scopes in the example explicitly:

```
ThisBuild / Zero / Zero / scalacOptions += "-Ywarn-unused-import"

lazy val projD = (project in file("d"))
  .settings(
    test := { println((Compile / console / scalacOptions).value) }
  )

projD / Zero / console / scalacOptions -= "-Ywarn-unused-import"
projD / Compile / Zero / scalacOptions := (projD / Zero / Zero / scalacOptions).value
```

I had to take out these two settings, to be able to refer to `projD`, but otherwise it's the same definition.

So from the first part you understood that `projD / Compile / Zero / scalacOptions` wins over `projD / Zero / console / scalacOptions` and `ThisBuild / ...`.

Now let's just take its value and use in our task. But what is its value? It refers to `projD / Zero / Zero / scalacOptions` which is not defined explicitly. So we need to find a delegate for it. At this moment we're already not competing with `projD / Compile` and `projD / console` and the only fitting key in scope is in the scope `ThisBuild / Zero / Zero`.

I tried to illustrate it here (ommitting the `/ scalacOptions` to save space):

```
projD     / Compile / console // the one we need in the task
projD     / Zero    / console // could be applied by rule 3, but looses to the next one:
projD     / Compile / Zero    // applies by rule 2 (task scope delegation), defined with next one:
projD     / Zero    / Zero    // not defined explicitly, so is delegated:
ThisBuild / Zero    / Zero    // applies by rule 4 (project scope delegation)
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer! I would like to ask one further question about your answer. You've mentioned, "At this moment we're already not competing with projD / Compile and projD / console and the only fitting key in scope is in the scope ThisBuild / Zero / Zero." I couldn't understand why the projD/ console is not a fitting key at the time when it tries to delegate for the key (projD/ Zero/ Zero). Is it because of the projD/ Zero/ console was not chosen at the first competition with projD/ compile/ Zero? I appreciate your help!

Comment: That's a good question, but I'm afraid I don't know the answer. I think you had a good guess about it: the search context changes and the keys already considered are excluded to avoiding cyclic definitions.